# HP EliteBook x360 1030 G8 (Ubuntu 22.04) suspend issues

Tags: suspend, 22.04, power-management, hp

I already search the web for a similar problem but can't find any useful solution so I'm asking here.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with 5.18 kernel and have issues with suspend (either by closing, lid, suspend timeout, or manuelly triggering it.)

Every time I want to resume, all I get is a black screen, no mouse, keyboard is not responding, CTRL+ALT+F1 doesn't work either.

System logs doesn't show any issues, only filling logs when I force reboot the laptop.

Already checked `/sys/power/mem_sleep` is set to `[s2idle] deep`.

I read somewhere that this could be the fault of HP BIOS having it's sleep states setup for Windows, that are not compatible with Ubuntu, but I can't even find an option named this way in the BIOS.

Has anyone ever encounter this issue ? Thanks for your help,

5.18 kernel was installed from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/), but I've had this issue with 5.15 kernel also.

Comment: Where did the 5.18 kernel come from?

Comment: @David it was manually installed from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/) but I've had this issue with 5.15 also.

Comment: You need to EDIT the question and add that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution, I edited the file `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`
as :

```
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=yes
#AllowHibernation=yes
#AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
AllowHybridSleep=yes
SuspendMode= platform standby
#SuspendState=mem standby freeze
#HibernateMode=platform shutdown
#HibernateState=disk
#HybridSleepMode=suspend platform shutdown
#HybridSleepState=disk
#HibernateDelaySec=180min
```

And it's now working.